# Calling class method in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a following scenario to call a class method in HTML on click of button.

Created on typescript file having one class.

On compiling this is converted to the js format.

i have on html page and i need to call a class function while clicking one button.

Help me to overcome this situation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Can not help you with out any code.